(Algebraic) monodromy group of $V \otimes V^*$
The algebraic monodromy group of a continuous semisimple (or irreducible further) representation $$\rho: G \to GL(V)=GL_n(\mathbb C)$$ is, by definition, the Zariski closure of the image of $\rho$ in the algebraic group $GL_V$. Let's denote this by $G_{\rho}$. I assumed the base field is $\mathbb C$, but it can be replaced by any algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$.
This linear algebraic group $G_{\rho}$ is reductive since we assume that $\rho$ is semisimple.
I wonder how much $G_{\rho}(\mathbb C)$ determines $G_{\rho \otimes \rho^*}(\mathbb C)$, where $\rho^*$ is the dual representation of $\rho$.
For example, if $G_{\rho}(\mathbb C)$ has the semisimple rank $r$, then it looks like that $G_{\rho \otimes \rho^*}(\mathbb C)$ also has the semisimple rank $r$, because the representation $\rho \otimes \rho^*$ is completely 'parametrized' by $\rho$ (I apologize that I use some unclear, indefinite terminology).
On the other hand, if we assume that $G_{\rho}(\mathbb C)$ is a semisimple group isomorphic to $Sp(V,B)$, where $B$ is the associated (non-degenerate) skew-symmetric bilinear pairing, then $\rho^*$ conserves a dual pairing $B^*$ on $V^*$ so that $\rho \otimes \rho^*$ conserves the pairing $B\otimes B^*$ on $V \otimes V^*$ which is symmetric.
Therefore, $G_{\rho \otimes \rho^*}(\mathbb C)$ is orthogonal in this case although $G_{\rho}(\mathbb C)$ is symplectic. So the following are questions that come from these contexts.

Is the semisimple rank of $G_{\rho}$ and $G_{\rho \otimes \rho^*}$ are the same?

If $G_{\rho}^{der}$ the derived subgroup of $G_{\rho}$ is isomorphic to either $SO_n$ or $Sp_n$, then $G_{\rho \otimes \rho}^{der}$ is isomorphic to $SO_n$? Moreover, can we determine $G_{\rho \otimes \rho^*}$ from $G_{\rho}$?


Thank you so much.

Let $f\colon \mathrm{GL}n\times\mathrm{GL}n\to \mathrm{GL}{n^2}$ be the tensor product map. Isn't $G{\rho\otimes\rho^}$ just ${f(g, g^{-t}) : g\in G_{\rho}}$? In particular, as abstract groups, $G_{\rho}$ and $G_{\rho\otimes\rho^}$ should be isomorphic, so have the same semisimple rank.

In particular, the answer to your second question is no. E.g. suppose that $\rho\colon G\to \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)\cong\mathrm{Sp}1(\mathbb C)$ is surjective. Then $\rho\otimes\rho^*\simeq \rho\otimes\rho\simeq \mathrm{Sym}^2(\rho) \oplus \mathbb{1}$. So $G{\rho\otimes\rho^*}$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)$, embedded into $\mathrm{GL}_3(\mathbb C)\hookrightarrow\mathrm{GL}_4(\mathbb C)$ via the symmetric square map.

@Mathmo123 Oh, you are right. I suddenly was confused that a closed subgroup of the orthogonal group is orthogonal, which is not true. Thank you so much.

out of curiosity, what was the context for this question? I think it’s the first time I’ve seen a question about algebraic monodromy groups on this site!

@Mathmo123 In the context of the study of algebraic monodromy groups of Galois representations, more precisely a compatible system of continuous semisimple $\ell$-adic representations of an absolute Galois group of a number field. Some papers I've read used the algebraic monodromy group of $\rho \otimes \rho^*$ for given $\rho$.

But I thought this question was completely on some basic stuff, so I asked this question in MSE instead of MO.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
